# Since S3 charges by request, couldn't a malicious hacker cause a huge AWS bill just by spamming requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, web-hosting, hacking

What would stop them from doing so, against, say, a static website hosted using S3? Is there a good way to deny some requests such that one avoids getting billed for them?

(Context: I want to host a static website on S3, but I wouldn't want to end up with a giant AWS bill because someone decided to spam requests.)

Comment: That is the risk with all per use solutions, if you can’t control the use costs can sky rocket. One possible approach: Don’t directly expose the S3 bucket but use for example cloudfront for offloading/access control

Comment: For most people it is not going to be an issue, until it is. With the standard and intelligent tier there needs to be 25 million requests to get to $10. The bigger cost would be egress bandwidth, which would be around 11TB for a 500KB object. I recommend using CloudFront because there is no reason not to and with caching enabled it should reduce the S3 Get requests. From there you can add WAF, but it is probably better to setup some budget alerts (maybe at $10 or something) and only add WAF when it actually becomes a problem. WAF will cost more than what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: AWS WAF can apply rate based rules to limit how many requests one IP can make. A DDOS can work around this, but there are separate mitigations for this. You could also use CloudFlare CDN which has a free tier that should protect against this. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/waf-apply-rate-limit/

Answer (score 0):

To deny requests, you would need to be hosting on a more flexible machine than a storage bucket. Cloud storage buckets are fast and cheap, but that's a little bit *because* they're so permissive and have few inherent security options.

If you really want to control traffic to S3, you would need a middleman. [From an aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/):

- [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcoaN.png), since I can't embed here yet

Services like CloudFront would be able to take the brunt of the user (and crawler) requests, decide who to serve, and ultimately reduce the amount of requests sent to the underlying S3. They can also do things like cache hashes for downloads, so that it doesn't eat a request when a user tries to update content they already have downloaded.

Oh and, unless you're a big company, you'll probably be able to stay in CF's free tier (1TB egress, unlimited fetch from S3, 10M reqs / month)